# What is the advantage of folded horn compared with unfolded one?

Tags: acoustics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxBUA.png)Looking at the video of disassembling the LRAD 300, it was a folded horn structure. I've been obsessed with exponential horn design so far, but what advantage does the folded horn structure have compared to the exponential horn structure? I was thinking that there was only the effect of lengthening the effective horn length. Is there any advantage other than directivity or matching problem? There seems to be insufficient data on the folded horn structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Folded horns occupy less physical space in a room; that is the only reason for folding them. They are significantly more difficult to construct than straight horns or ported enclosures.